# Blob for Commitments

Tags: multiparty-computation, commitments

I am currently reading the paper Multiparty Unconditional Secure Protocols (https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/62212.62214). They use blob for commitments. The purpose of blobs is to allow a participant $P_i$ to commit to a bit in such a
way that she cannot later change her mind about the bit, but nobody else can discover it without her help.

How is the cut and choose procedure useful here so that $P_i$ cannot open a blob as both $0$ and $1$.